# Spot instances termination

Tags: amazon-ec2, volatility

I'm planning to start using Amazon EC2, and, as everyone, I want to use Spot instances.

Will be for a minigames server, so Spot instances are perfect for this. Players enter, play the match and leave, so when a Spot instance finishes because of spot instance price volatility only current match will be finished, barely any data loss and perfectly acceptable when you save a lot of money.

Now, altough players are going to be disconnected and connected to an ondemand server when volatility reaches maximum bid, I would like to know if when a Spot instance is force-terminated is called the normal shutdown command or simply is "unplugged" and I don't have a chance to disconnect players safely and save their data to the database (this will take just a few milliseconds).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of 2015, Amazon now provides a 2-minute termination notice in the instance metadata.

A custom script can be written to poll for the termination notice and call web server graceful shutdown and associated cleanup scripts to ensure zero impact to end-users.

Source: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-ec2-spot-instance-termination-notices/